# Why do I wake up so many times in the middle of the night

Tags: sleep-deprivation, waking-up, sleep-apnea, restless-sleep, nocturia

I am 31 years old and for many years I wake up between 5-8 times at night and I have to switch from one side to another. I don't have any issue of falling back to sleep.

For me it feels that I am very agitated, other persons that slept with me told me this also (because I move a lot in bed)

Is this a sleeping issue ? If yes, what can I do about it ?
What I want is just fall asleep and when I wake up is morning.

And I must say I am not stressed at all with anything and I am a very chill and relaxing person.

Comment: Have you ever been tested for sleep apnea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK: It's pretty normal as long that you don't have trouble getting back to sleep.
Try to google 'sleep cycles' to learn more about how the brain functions. Basically we have, I recall, 4 stages of sleep. Stage 4 is what is known as REM sleep, and this is where vivid dreaming happends, stages 3 is deep sleep and so on ...
The point I'm getting to, is that a complete sleep cycle will take approx. 90min, and after a complete cycle you're back at stage 1, where you'll be mildly awake again.
Info is based on recollection and might not be 100% accurate.

Cheers,
Tobias

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). Since health is a sensitive topic, accurate information, [backed up with reliable references](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) is what we are looking for. You can always [edit] your answer to add references. Thanks!